# Keep PHP error_log files outside of web root

Tags: php, security, error-handling, web, error-logging

Currently, when a PHP error occurs, it will log it into a file called error_log in the same directory the error occurred in.
How can I keep the error_log files outside of the web root so that users cannot view them, for security?

Comment: Onestly, this is the first time i see php error logs in the webroot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your php.ini file.  Find the error_log setting and change it to the full path of where you want the error_log file to be written.